main.ts:67 An error happened during loading the FBX file: Error: THREE.FBXLoader: Cannot find the version number for the file given
main.ts.. An error happened during loading the FBX file: Error: THREE.FBXLoader: Cannot find the version number for the file given.
at getFbxVersion (...)
at FBXLoader.parse (...)
at Object.onLoad (...)
at ...
local
code
dkgdmgodmpghmpdomh gmfdkmgkldngjnejnrtuiwhrfuihsdibnfjhQBUREVGaUYIgdiuBNDJKLQBNARJKBAWESUIOGHDFIOZHTIONWJLNT5JKERSNGUIOVHSUIHTWEUIRTYG
